# Google maps has stopped working on android after I switched from windows to linux

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am developing an app which requires google maps on android. Earlier I was developing on Windows and everything was working perfectly. A few days ago I switched to ubuntu and the maps suddenly stopped working. I have added the sha1 key to the console -

```
API key:    
AIzaSyDD3ntjHTCKntDoVJt7J_eMZs-t7lYIlZ8
Android apps:   
98:26:30:05:AF:D7:74:3F:5F:C1:BF:D6:24:80:5E:9B:DC:F4:F4:D6;com.opaxlabs.boatbrat EB:53:F8:2A:B3:05:63:5E:3F:CF:17:47:63:A8:8B:FA:C8:67:30:D4;com.opaxlabs.boatbrat
Activated on:   Jun 25, 2014 5:07 AM
```

So that I have two sha1 fingerprints. I switched back to windows to check and the app was working perfectly there. The error in log cat states that -

```
Google Maps Android API(10773): Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
```

The build when run on devices shows a blank screen where there should be a map.
The api key is mentioned in the manifest as -

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDD3ntjHTCKntDoVJt7J_eMZs-t7lYIlZ8" />
```

Also in the emulator it asks me to update the api showing me a button to update which when clicked crashes the app. Please help me with your suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Edit:
The problem seems to be in the fact(Although I am not sure about it) that I had created a demo project on the google console and put the sha1 in it. Later I created a project and put a sha1 in that too. It seems that it was taking the key from the demo project and not the proper project. I have deleted the contents of the demo project but to no avail. Is there a way to correct this problem?

Comment: In the console you added each sha1 on a separate line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like an issue with the api key.

Generate sha1 of the debug certificate on your ubuntu, and add it to the api console as another key in addition to the sha1 of certificate from windows.

That should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open terminal
2. navigate to /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin (bin of java )
3. write On terminal :-  keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android
   4.copy the SHA1 key and  paste in place of the previous SHA1 of your windows
4. dont change anything else.

its working......

Answer (score 0):

1. Regenerate sha on your pc,
2. Go to google console,
3. Create new Android key (for google map),**(delete the old)**
   **For Linux:** 
   `keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`
4. Copy sha with name of your project , for example: (Sha;projectname)
   **98:26:30:05:AF:D7:74:3F:5F:C1:BF:D6:24:80:5E:9B:DC:F4:F4:D6;com.example.androidapp**
5. Copy API key to app.

In google console your **Android apps** have 2 times sha and project name.

Comment: I tried deleting the old fingerprints and adding a new one, but still it does not work I still get a blank screen instead of a map.